# Cmake Could NOT find PythonLibs

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, vim, cmake

I'm trying to download [YouCompleteMe](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#full-installation-guide) for Vim on Windows following [this tutorial](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#full-installation-guide).

When calling CMake:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64" -DPATH_TO_LLVM_ROOT=%USERPROFILE%/ycm_temp/llvm_root_dir . %USERPROFILE%/vimfiles/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
```

It throws the following exception:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
(Required is at least version "2.6")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:262 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
CMakeLists.txt:189 (find_package)
```

I have installed python-2.7.13, and put it under `PATH` in `Environment Variables`.

What should I do to fix the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64" -DPATH_TO_LLVM_ROOT=%USERPROFILE%/ycm_temp/llvm_root_dir . %USERPROFILE%/vimfiles/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
```

You should set the `DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` and `DPYTHON_LIBRARY` flags to something like below:

```
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Python27\include \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\libs
```

If you use the default install path (C:\Python27), the full command is shown below:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64" -DPATH_TO_LLVM_ROOT=%USERPROFILE%/ycm_temp/llvm_root_dir . %USERPROFILE%/vimfiles/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Python27\include -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\libs
```