# CMake Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake

I'm trying to install gFootball (https://github.com/google-research/football) in a virtual environment created by pyenv but run into this error when I try `pip3 install gfootball`:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
      Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
      (Required is at least version "3")
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
      /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:310 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
      CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)
```

It looks like the most common solution is either specifying certain environment variables ([Cmake Could NOT find PythonLibs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601548/cmake-could-not-find-pythonlibs/44601549)) or installing python-dev with `sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python3-dev` ([CMake can not find PythonLibs while building OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474976/cmake-can-not-find-pythonlibs-while-building-opencv)). I had trouble trying to install python3-dev (I'm on a mac, I tried with homebrew but it didn't work). I don't really know how to specify the specific environment variables though, or what that even means exactly. Where would I put them? What would the steps to do so look like? I'm not familiar at all with CMake

They recommend using Docker but I've never used that before, so I wanted to get it working with my pyenv virtual environments. I didn't think that would be an issue

Any help or suggestions is appreciated